# How to get the last N lines from an unlimited Popen.stdout object

Tags: python, popen, lines

I'm trying to get the last N lines from an unlimited Popen.stdout object at the current time. And by unlimited I mean unlimited/many log entries which are getting written to stdout.
I tried Popen.stdout.readline() limited by time, but this just produce a whole lot of random issues, especially with little output.
Some sort of snapshot of the current output would help me, but I am unable to find anything like that. All the solutions I mostly find are for external processes which terminate, but mine is an server application which should be able to write to stdout after I read the last lines.

Greetings,

Faerbit

Comment: Maybe overkill, even though it's a simple library: I'd recommend `pexpect` for this job.  At least it solves issues like the subprogram buffering a whole page of data because its stdout does not appear to be a terminal.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would help me. It seems to have the same methods for reading stuff as Popen has. (Also their webpage is very weird.)

Comment: Can you give a clearer example of what you mean by 'unlimited' Popen ? is it like you having Popen'ed subprocess like a webserver which is constantly spewing out log entries and then you want to get N lines of it as and when you want in the controlling main process?

Comment: Yeah, could have made that clearer. The data of the stdout is unlimited/very large. It is a log of a minecraft server. And now I want to communicate with it. The input part works flawless. But I'm unable to get the output. Just like you thought!

Answer (score 0):

On Unix, when you launch your process you can pipe it into `tail` first:

```
p=subprocess.Popen("your_process.sh | tail --lines=3", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
r=p.communicate()
print r[0]
```

Usage of `shell=True` is the key here.

Comment: This doesn't work because you missed the key problem: The output is unlimited! tail as well as communicate() work only on processes that terminate. On server logs this doesn't work, because your server should be running all the time.

Comment: What is the last N lines than?

Comment: Consider `tee`ing output into a file, and the periodically run `tail` on that file. If output goes to log file already, you can `tail` the log file

Comment: The whole reason for chosing python, was not to deal with buffering. So I'm really interested in a solutiuon which directly accesses the stdout stream.